# I want to force file open when directory is not exist

Tags: c++, c

When i open file by the next way:
ofstream outputFile(Filename, ios::out | ios::binary);

i gets error result when the directory not exist:

temp\filename.ext

when the directory exist it work well. 
I want to know how can i force the operation in c++ command

Comment: How do you expect to open a file that doesn't exist? Your code should check that the file exists before attempting to open it, and if not it should attempt to create it if needs be.

Comment: What language? C or C++?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no standardized way to create a directory in c++.
You might want to take a look at the [filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) from boost. There are multiple functions for checking if the directory/file exits and if not how to create them.

Comment: mkdir() works on pretty much all the OSes (although the syntax is a bit different on Windows and Linux).

Comment: @Radu: "the syntax is a bit different" ;-) That is my definition of no standardized way.

Comment: Even so, it's just a few #ifdefs, so in effect it is as close at it can be to the standard :) And of course, one can make a macro for it.

Answer (score 1):

The file is created automatically when creating an `ofstream` if it does not exist. But the directory where you want this file to be created must already exist.

There is no way to create a directory automatically in C++. You have to create the directory in C++.

Furthermore, and unfortunately, there's no C++ standard way of dealing with directories. You'll have to revert to the C system library `mkdir` of your operating system to create it.

Comment: mkdir is linux file system app. i needs c++ or c function for linux and windows. as you understand my application is cross platform app

Comment: On Windows, the C runtime of Visual C++ provides the function `_mkdir`. Interface is straightforward. Using an `mkdir` and `_mkdir` macro switch depending on platform is lightweight compared to using full featured libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the first to admit I know nothing about C, but in any programming language trying to force an open file operation on a file that doesn't exist is a BAD THING!

Check if the file you're trying to open exists.  If it doesn't, create it.  If you can't create it, then fail gracefully.

Comment: It's not a matter of file existing or not. It's a matter of inexistent directory when a file is created.

Comment: Indeed, you generally will not find C or C++ functions (or functions in most other languages) that only create files. You open them; if you open a non-existent file for reading, it's an error. If you open a non-existent file for _writing_, it is created. That's how you create files.